# Google reCaptcha in JSF response g-recaptcha-response null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, httprequest, recaptcha

I'm trying to use [Google ReCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) in my jsf project.
I've successfully render the gui like this:

```
<h:form id="contact-form" class="contact-form">   
    <p:panelGrid styleClass="submitGrid" columns="2">
         <div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="dark" data-sitekey="my-site-Key"></div>
            <p class="contact-submit">
               <p:commandButton id="contact-submit" styleClass="submit" value="Send" action="#{questionaryBean.validation()}" update="contact-submit,confirmDlg, contact-form" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()"/>
            </p>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

And here's my backing bean:

```
public void save(){
    Map<String,String> requestParams = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
  requestParams.get("reportKey");
  for(String key:requestParams.keySet()){
      System.out.println("key:"+key+" value:"+requestParams.get(key));
  }
}
```

As you can see, I printed all of the request parameters, but I can't see g-recaptcha-response here. And of course if I use `String gRecaptchaResponse=requestParams.get("g-recaptcha-response");` ,the String `gRecaptchaResponse` is null.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Analuze the http network traffic with your browser developertool

Comment: Can you tell me how to analyze the http network traffic with the browser developer tool? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, no, I have no time nor desire to go into those things here. Try to post the exact question in the comment above in google and add your favourite browser name to it. You'll get approximately 10.000 hits then.